# DNS forward to Windows DNS not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, domain-name-system, active-directory

A Ubuntu 20.04 server was the internet gateway that was also a dns forwarder. External lookups were forwarded for to Internet and local requests directed to the Windows domain controller that was the internal dns server. The gateway was recently updated to 22.04 which broke the resolution for internal hosts. Nothing about the forwarding configuration changed, so why did it work previously but now fails?

Comment: hi Michael, please edit this question to be a question And down below, add your answer! Else this request does not make any sense :)

Comment: "Once the following was added to named.conf to disable the cookie" It would be far better to instead fix the server mishandling the cookies. Continuing to use broken DNS software will only give you further problems in the future. The DNS community wisdom is that cookies are useful and should be used.

Comment: @djdomi appreciate the feedback and hopefully the modification makes sense.

Comment: @patrick-mevzek unfortunately this situation frequently occurs when working with legacy technologies that were developed during a time when security was not given much thought. I cannot force another group to "fix something that's not broken".

Comment: @MichaelB.Gilliam below the question, there is an answer field. Please use this if it's already resolved, that was what i meant. :-)

Comment: "I cannot force another group to "fix something that's not broken". " In 2022 having DNS software not capable of handling is seriously in the "broken" category. It is right in the specification (RFC 7873 §5.1): "   At a server where DNS Cookies are not implemented and enabled, the
   presence of a COOKIE option is ignored and the server responds as if
   no COOKIE option had been included in the request." It shouldn't reply with an error... `FORMERR` on the other end should be used only if the cookie content is malformed.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question to hopefully save someone else all the time and effort to resolve a recent situation

After the device was upgraded to 22.04 the internal dns queries returned with **received FORMERR resolving**. This was perplexing because locally doing a nslookup using the windows server worked, but the dig command point at the windows dns failed. Turns out the is the standard message from windows DNS when a request with the EDNS cookie enabled option set. The EDNS cookie is enabled on the latest version of bind by default. Once the following was added to named.conf to disable the cookie, the service restarted, everything worked as expected.

```
    In BIND 9.10.x the option to do this is "request-sit no; "
    From BIND 9.11.0 onwards, it is "send-cookie no; "send-cookie no; "
```

DNS COOKIES are enabled in all builds from BIND 9.11.0 forward. Note that the cookie policy was very lenient in the original implementation for a low-impact introduction, and is 'tightened' in BIND 9.11.26, 9.16.10, 9.17.8, and later versions, as described below.
To use it in the BIND 9.10 branch, build BIND with "configure --enable-sit".
It is enabled by default for Windows builds from BIND 9.10.3 and higher.